# Subnet IPv6 subnet /64 into /126 using python netaddr library

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ipv6, subnet

I have a /64 IP subnet, I need to subnet that /64 and I need to get 100 /126 ip subnets from it. I am trying to use Python netaddr library to do it. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to break a /64 into smaller networks. See RFC 5375, IPv6 Unicast Address Assignment Considerations, "Using a subnet prefix length other than a /64 will break many features of IPv6..."

RFC 6164, Using 127-Bit IPv6 Prefixes on Inter-Router Links, allows for /127 point-to-point links, "Routers MUST support the assignment of /127 prefixes on point-to-point inter-router links."

And, of course you are allowed to us /128 for loppback addresses.

All that said, you should only take a single /127 or /128 out of a /64. Subdividing a /64 into multiple subnets is unnecessary and just asking for trouble.  We need to change our mindsets from IPv4 scarcity to IPv6 plenty since there is no problems getting as many /64 blocks as you need; anyone can request and get a /48 which is 65536 /64 networks.